# Задача "Банковский вклад" (с помощью функций)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Хотелось бы узнать решение ниже приведённой задачи, **решается с помощью функций:**

> Иван кладет в банк **x** рублей под **a** процентов годовых на **n** лет. Напишите функцию, которая возвращает число - сколько денег получит Иван в результате. Функция принимает три числа и возвращает одно - итоговая сумма на счету Ивана после **n** лет.

Comment: Здравствуйте на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из формулы сложных процентов:

[image: s]

t = Общее время в годax
n = число периодов наращения в год
r = Номинальная годовая процентная ставка выражается в виде десятичной дроби
nt = означает, что nt округляется до ближайшего целого числа.

P.S. Число наращевания в год (n) по условии задачи нам не требуется, т.е. `n = 1`.

```
foo = lambda x, a, n: x * (1 + a / 100) ** n
```

Пример:

```
foo(1000, 10, 1) 
1100 # за 1 год, Иван заработает 10% от 1000 (т.е. 100) и у него будет 1100
```